# Tensorflow build with bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

T try to compile tensorflow with bazel. 
I following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition#usage_with_the_c_api

I use (on Debian 9.4):

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/...
```

And error:

```
    bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/...
/usr/local/bin/bazel: line 88: /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/usr/local/bin/bazel: line 88: /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real: Success
```

And nothing be build.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What steps did you take to install Bazel?

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed wrong bazel for your platform. Can you follow the instructions on https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html and see if that helps?

Comment: I had the same issue with Bazel 0.23.0 on Ubuntu 18.4. I uninstalled it and then reinstalled Bazel 0.26.1 at it worked for me.